# Change the default page layout used for new sites

Tags: page-layout

When a create a new publishing site within my site collection, a default welcome page for the site is automatically created which always uses the layout file /_catalogs/masterpage/WelcomeLinks.aspx (Welcome page with summary links). This layout is used by default even when it is excluded from the list of allowed layouts.

How can I change things so that a different layout file is used by default?

Answer (score 1):

The default welcome page layout is defined in the OOTB publishing site definition.
If you want to set your own welcome page automatically after creating a new publishing site - you have the following options AFAIK:

- Create a new site with the OOTB publishing template. Set your desired welcome page layout. Save the site as a template via "/_layouts/savetmpl.aspx"
- Create a custom webtemplate /
  sitedefinition

Answer (score 1):

This is an old thread above, but I had the same problem and found the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4190576/sharepoint-how-do-i-change-the-default-page-layout-for-newly-created-subsites.

Answer (score 0):

MY first question would be iust what is set up as the default page layout as specified on this page.

http://servername/_Layouts/AreaTemplateSettings.aspx

Could it be that the welcome page is listed here?  It looks like you covered this already but worth double checking.  This is also set at the Site Collection level.  Make sure you double check the context of the site you are working.

Comment: I don't see any way of setting a default layout at http://servername/_Layouts/AreaTemplateSettings.aspx, only a list of allowed layouts, and even if layout which is currently being used as a default is remove from the allowed list, it still gets used, although if you then manual change its layout you can't change it back to the delisted one.